# Confusion regarding confidence interval

Tags: matlab, regression

I was using matlab's cftool to fit a regression line to my data point x and y. And I could see this

```
Linear model Poly1:
     f(x) = p1*x + p2
Coefficients (with 95% confidence bounds):
       p1 =       1.039  (0.8671, 1.212)
       p2 =     -0.6122  (-1.581, 0.3569)

Goodness of fit:
  SSE: 2.228
  R-square: 0.9668
  Adjusted R-square: 0.962
  RMSE: 0.5642
```

I didn't get this 95% confidence interval was generated.

Comment: Are you asking how matlab comes up with the 95% confidence-bounds for the coefficients p1 and p2?

Comment: I mean how it was calculated. I know what confidence interval is. I mean it is the interval around the estimated parameter within which the true parameter is expected to lie. I want to know how it was calculated in this case by matlab. I don't think it has sufficient data to calculate the interval. I mean given my data points how can I calculate the confidence interval of the estimated parameters which is the parameters of the linear regression in this case

Comment: I mean to be specific I have lets say 10 pairs of x,y variables so my sample size n = 10. I got the parameters for the regression p1 and p2. But where is the standard deviation so that I can get the interval?